# What's the way using Sparx Enterprise Architecture by different user?

Tags: content-management-system, enterprise-architect, technical-indicator, branching-strategy

As Sparx EA is a versatile software, I want to know how we can use it in a team, by different levels of admin, and how we can create different level of access? it's possible by cloud that exist in Sparx sources? or can we execute it in internal network?

My problem is in creating user; I've searched it in google and also on Sparx website but I couldn't find my answer.

Comment: Sorry mate, but that would need a book as answer. Hire a consultant...

Comment: can I ask some question in detail about this title of you?

Comment: Either you ask a question or not. But don't ask it you can ask a question...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/model_security/usersecurity.html

You need a key that comes with your licence to [turn on security](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.1/model_security/usersecurity2.html) in your model. You can set up users and groups with different levels of access within Sparx EA. When the model is first opened, the user needs to login using either a model-contained user/pwd or Windows Active Directory login depending on how you set it up.

If you're using a SQL server on a LAN to host your model you can use your environment's setup to control access to the database/model too.